# face alignment algorithm on images

Tags: objective-c, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, biometrics

How can I do a basic face alignment on a 2-dimensional image with the assumption that I have the position/coordinates of the mouth and eyes.

Is there any algorithm that I could implement to correct the face alignment on images?

Comment: One idea would be to build a relation between location of eyes and mouth with the deviation in alignment. Then use this relation to correct the position by padding image matrix and adjusting the scale by calling [cv::resize](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-resize) function with calculated scale differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Face (or image) alignment refers to aligning one image (or face in your case) with respect to another (or a reference image/face). It is also referred to as image registration. You can do that using either appearance (*intensity-based registration*) or key-point locations (*feature-based registration*). The second category stems from image motion models where one image is considered a displaced version of the other.

In your case the landmark locations (3 points for eyes and nose?) provide a good reference set for straightforward feature-based registration. Assuming you have the location of a set of points in both of the 2D images, `x_1` and `x_2` you can estimate a *similarity transform* (rotation, translation, scaling), i.e. a planar 2D transform `S` that maps `x_1` to `x_2`. You can additionally add reflection to that, though for faces this will most-likely be unnecessary.

Estimation can be done by forming the normal equations and solving a linear least-squares (LS) problem for the `x_1 = Sx_2` system using linear regression. For the 5 unknown parameters (2 rotation, 2 translation, 1 scaling) you will need 3 points (2.5 to be precise) for solving 5 equations. Solution to the above LS can be obtained through Direct Linear Transform (e.g. by applying SVD or a matrix pseudo-inverse). For cases of a sufficiently large number of reference points (i.e. automatically detected) a RANSAC-type method for point filtering and uncertainty removal (though this is not your case here).

After estimating `S`, apply image warping on the second image to get the transformed grid (pixel) coordinates of the entire `image 2`. The transform will change pixel locations but not their appearance. Unavoidably some of the transformed regions of `image 2` will lie outside the grid of `image 1`, and you can decide on the values for those null locations (e.g. 0, NaN etc.).

For more details: R. Szeliski, "[Image Alignment and Stitching: A Tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=75695)" (Section 4.3 "Geometric Registration")

In OpenCV see: [Geometric Image Transformations](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html), e.g. `cv::getRotationMatrix2D` `cv::getAffineTransform` and `cv::warpAffine.` Note though that you should estimate and apply a similarity transform (special case of an affine) in order to preserve angles and shapes.

Answer (score 1):

For the face there is lot of variability in feature points. So it won't be possible to do a perfect fit of all feature points by just affine transforms. The only way to align all the points perfectly is to warp the image given the points. Basically you can do a triangulation of image given the points and do a affine warp of each triangle to get the warped image where all the points are aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Face detection could be handled based on the just eye positions.

Herein, OpenCV, Dlib and MTCNN offers to detect faces and eyes. Besides, it is a python based framework but deepface wraps those methods and offers an out-of-the box detection and alignment function.

detectFace function applies detection and alignment in the background respectively.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn']
DeepFace.detectFace("img.jpg", detector_backend = backends[0])
```

Besides, you can apply detection and alignment manually.

```
from deepface.commons import functions
img = functions.load_image("img.jpg")
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn']

detected_face = functions.detect_face(img = img, detector_backend = backends[3])
plt.imshow(detected_face)

aligned_face = functions.align_face(img = img, detector_backend = backends[3])
plt.imshow(aligned_face)

processed_img = functions.detect_face(img = aligned_face, detector_backend = backends[3])
plt.imshow(processed_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a section *Aligning Face Images* in OpenCV's Face Recognition guide:

- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#aligning-face-images

The script aligns given images at the eyes. It's written in Python, but should be easy to translate to other languages. I know of a C# implementation by Sorin Miron:

- http://code.google.com/p/stereo-face-recognition/