# Pose correction for face recognition

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have a dataset of images with faces. I also have for each face within the dataset a set of 66 2D points that correspond to my face landmarks(nose, eyes, shape of my face, mouth).

So basically I have the shape of my face in terms of 2D points from my image.

Do you know any algorithm that I can use and that can rotate my shape so that the face shape is straight? Let's say that the pan angle is 30 degrees and I want it rotated to 30 degrees so that it is positioned at 0 degrees on the pan angle. I have illustrated bellow what I want to say.

[image]

[image]

Basically you can consider the above illustrated shapes outlines for my images, which are represented in 2D. I want to rotate my first shape points so that they can look like the second shape. A shape is made out of a set of `66 2D points which are basically pixel coordinates`. All I want to do is to find the correspondence of each of those `66 points` so that the new shape is rotated with a certain degree on the pan angle.

Comment: Do you know the depth of each 2d point?  The only reason your rotation looks like that is because the nose and mouth are actually in front of the jawline.

Comment: Do you want to rotate the shape point coordinates (i.e. the 66 2D landmarks), so you will have a frontal shape (outline) or to warp an image (that corresponds to those 2D points) to a frontal looking pose? To rephrase that: do you want to transform the point coordinates ("shape") or warp image intensity values ("texture").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question, I can assume you either have the rotation parameters (e.g. degrees in x,y) or the point correspondences (since you have a database of matched points). Thus you either need to apply or estimate (and apply) a 2D similarity transformation for image alignment/registration. See also the response on this question:  [face alignment algorithm on images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046462/face-alignment-algorithm-on-images/12048097#12048097)

**From rotation angle and to new point locations**: You can define a 2D rotation matrix `R` and transform your point coordinates with it.

**From point correspondences between shape A and Shape B to rotation**: Estimate a 2D similarity transform (image alignment) using 3 or more matching points.

**From either rotation or point correspondences to warped image**: From the similarity transform, map image values (accounting for interpolation or non-values) using the underlying coordinate transformation for the entire image grid.

[image: point-constrained image warping]
*(image courtesy of Denis Simakov, [AAM Slides](http://denis.simakov.info/weizmann/slides.php))*

Most of these are already implemented in OpenCV and MATLAB. See also the background and relevant methods around Active Shape and [Active Appearance Models](http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/timothy.f.cootes/Models/aam.html) (Tim Cootes page includes binaries and background material).